# different output in conways game of life

Tags: java, output, conways-game-of-life

I have to create a Java program for Conway's Game Of Life in procedural manner and I'm only one step away from finishing - all I have left to do is figure out how to make the output change itself(something like a GIF). Instead, my program outputs all the results one by one. I'm figuring it should be some kind of a loop, but I'm not sure. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Random;                                                                   
import java.util.Scanner;                                                                  

class gameOfLife {                                                                         
public static void main(String[] args) {                                               

    //User input                                                                       

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);                                               
    System.out.println("How many rows?");                                              
    int rows = in.nextInt();                                                           
    System.out.println("How many columns?");                                           
    int cols = in.nextInt();                                                           

    //Declaring variables and grids                                                    

    int[][] grid = new int[rows][cols];                                                
    int[][] nextGrid = new int[rows][cols];                                            
    int[][] temp = new int [rows][cols];                                               

    //Initializing first generation                                                    

    initiateGrid(grid);                                                                
    printGameBoard(grid);                                                              

    //Looping through 10 generations                                                   

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {                                                     
        applyTheRules(grid, rows, cols, nextGrid);                                     
        temp = nextGrid;                                                               
        nextGrid = grid;                                                               
        grid = temp;                                                                   
        printGameBoard(grid);                                                          
    }                                                                                  
}                                                                                      

//Initiating first generation grid randomly                                            

static void initiateGrid(int[][] grid) {                                               
    Random r = new Random();                                                           
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {                                            
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {                                     
            grid[i][j] = r.nextInt(2);                                                 
        }                                                                              
    }                                                                                  
}                                                                                      

//Printing out the game board                                                          

static void printGameBoard(int[][] grid) {                                             
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {                                            
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {                                     
            if (grid[i][j] == 0)                                                       
                System.out.print(" . ");                                               
            else                                                                       
                System.out.print(" ■ ");                                               
        }                                                                              
        System.out.println();                                                          
    }                                                                                  
    System.out.println();                                                              
}                                                                                      

//Applying the rules of the game                                                       

static void applyTheRules(int [][] grid, int rows, int cols, int [][] nextGrid) {      
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                                                   
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {                                               
            int count = 0;                                                             
            if(i-1>=0 && i+1<grid.length && j-1>=0 && j+1<grid[i].length) {            
                for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {                                        
                    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {                                    
                        count += grid[i + x][j + y];                                   
                    }                                                                  
                }                                                                      
                count -= grid[i][j];                                                   

            } else{                                                                    
                     for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {                                   
                         for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {                               
                             count += 0;                                               
                         }                                                             
                     }                                                                 
                }                                                                      

            //Alive cell becomes dead, if there are more than                          
            //3 or less than 2 neighbouring cells                                      

            if((grid[i][j]==1)&&(count<2)||(count>3))                                  
                nextGrid[i][j]=0;                                                      

            //Dead cell becomes alive if there are exactly 3 neighbouring cells        

            else if((grid[i][j]==0)&&(count==3))                                       
                nextGrid[i][j]=1;                                                      

            //State stays the same                                                     

            else                                                                       
                nextGrid[i][j]=grid[i][j];                                             
        }                                                                              
    }                                                                                  
}
```

}

Comment: Doing something like that when all you have is text output is a bit difficult. There are text output "terminals" that allow you to clear the screen so that the board looks like it repaints itself. But that's not standard and may not work on somebody else's environment. It's best to use a GUI for this.

Comment: It was my initial idea to use GUI, but my professor said that I should do this task without GUI. What are these text output terminals that you mentioned?

Comment: A window like Windows `cmd` or something, where you run the  command. It may allow you to send an escape sequence that clears the screen. But it may not work in an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, and it will probably not work in IDEOne, etc. As I said - it's not standard.